# Saving as STL File

Tags: export

my english is not so good, im from germany xD

[image]

for short: when I save this File https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/83856

as STL file with Blender, it looks like she is wearing some kind of glasses.

How can I prevent that to happen ?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a rigged model, there are lots of dummy objects and controllers, remove them or unselect tgem before exporting

Answer (score 1):

In the left panel when you save there are an option unchecked, select it, "**Selection only**" and then export to STL, but before select only the mesh of rabbit.

Comment: Thank You :D Problem solved i have deleted the eyes rig. Im so Noob xD https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Kj3.jpg